# Trouble with drag events in MacRuby app

Tags: ruby, cocoa, macruby

It's been a while since I've done any Cocoa development, and I'm trying to get this very quick and dirty (and simple) app wrapped up. I decided to use MacRuby because it was a good excuse to learn it, and the app is simple enough that it made sense.

I'm having trouble getting a custom view to respond to drag events, though.

```
class ImportPanel < Panel
  def initWithFrame(frame)
    registerForDraggedTypes(NSArray.arrayWithObjects(NSPasteboardTypeSound, nil))
    super(frame)
  end

  def mouseDown(event)
    NSLog('click')
  end

  def draggingEntered(sender)
    NSLog('drag')
  end
end
```

Panel, in this case, is just an NSView that adds a border. This custom view (ImportPanel) is responding correctly to click events, but not reacting at all to drag events. I have tried several different pasteboard types and configurations for registerForDraggedTypes:, but none seem to produce any results.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me.

`AppDelegate.rb`

```
class AppDelegate
    attr_accessor :window
    attr_accessor :panel

    def applicationDidFinishLaunching(a_notification)
        # nothing special here
    end

    def initialize
        @panel = Panel.new

        # Just for debug
        puts @panel
    end
end
```

And this is my `player.rb`:

```
class Panel < NSView
    def awakeFromNib
        registerForDraggedTypes(NSArray.arrayWithObjects(NSFilenamesPboardType, NSURLPboardType, NSStringPboardType, nil))
    end

    def mouseDown(event)
        NSLog('click')
    end

    def draggingEntered(sender)
        NSLog('drag')
        return NSDragOperationNone
    end
end
```

The array of dragged types it's that way to help me testing different dragging operations (A URL, a file etc.). Note that draggingEntered needs to return an `NSDragOperation` i used `NSDragOperationNone` for just to see if it works.